# changing DOM element after document loading

Tags: javascript, events, dom

Have simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function(){
      document.getElementById( 'dog' ).src = 'https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/122163343-conditioning-dog-loud-noises-632x475.jpg';
      document.getElementById( 'dog' ).alt = 'Doggy';
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <img id="dog" src="" alt="">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I catch IMG element downloading? Tried to use mutations but unsuccessfully

Comment: Can you please give an explanation of "unsuccessfully"?

Comment: problem is solved, thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 1):

The download starts at `.src =`.

You can subscribe on the load event to check when it is done.

```
img.onload = () => console.log('Done!');
```

You can also check the boolean `complete`

```
if (img.complete) { }
```

Comment: My fault, the fact is that I have lot of downloaded images in one DIV container. Is there some way to detect downloading all of these without setting listeners for each?